# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error onds to your MySQL s se vnom)' at line 1

Tags: php, mysqli

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO employee (cin,nom) VALUES(:cin,:nom)';

try{
    $requete=$db->query($sql);
    $requete->bindValue(':cin',$emp->GetCin(),PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $requete->bindValue(':nom',$emp->GetNom(),PDO::PARAM_STR);   

    $requete->execute();
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    die("erreur".$e->getMessage());
}
```

When executing this code, the following error arises:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':cin,:nom)'

How to fix?

Comment: i would like to insert the employee  in the data base

Answer (score 1):

`$db->query()` executes the query as is.

The query you are using requires that you first prepare the statement, bind parameters and then execute the query. Otherwise, the tuple after `VALUES` is interpreted as data.

In order to fix this, use `$db->prepare()`. ([Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php))

```
$requete=$db->prepare($sql);
$requete->bindValue(':cin',$emp->GetCin(),PDO::PARAM_STR);
$requete->bindValue(':nom',$emp->GetNom(),PDO::PARAM_STR);   

$requete->execute();
```